# In the state of Connecticut are insurers required to pay for fees related to registering a new vehicle

Tags: insurance, connecticut

My car was totaled and I am not at fault. Is the at-fault's insurer responsible for costs associated with my having to get a new car including all required fees necessary to register the vehicle in Connecticut?

Is there any way to coerce them to pay for these fees I surely should not be responsible for?

Answer (score 3):

### The at-fault driver’s insurer has no liability to you

The at-fault drive has liability (under the tort of negligence) for which their insurer indemnified them. Any negotiation or settlement offers that insurer makes is on behalf of the driver. The distinction is important because if you were to sue, you would sue the driver, not the insurer.

### What are they liable for?

They must restore you to the position you were in before the accident- by repairing your car or giving you the cash equivalent (i.e. market value of the second-hand car). They do not have to get you a replacement car.